# PhoneGap file write to absolute path in windows store / windows 8 apps

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps, filewriter

I am fighting with the PhoneGap-Plugin for file writing in windows store apps. I can't find a way to save a file outside the "sandbox" the app is installed in.

example:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.getFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\my\local\folder\test.html").then(...
```

I found a confusing comment in this thread: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d94f271e-50ee-436b-8ba2-630ea6239f8d/storagefolder-from-absolute-path

> I could be wrong, but Metro's sandboxing only lets you access files that have been chosen, 
>   by the user, through file pickers.

Is this true? It would fit to my experiences because this works with files from a save picker.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the only areas an app can access programmatically are (a) your local, temp, and roaming appdata folders, and (b) any libraries for which you've declared a capability in the manifest.

For anything else, you must first acquire the StorageFolder or StorageFile object through a file picker. The use of the file picker is what obtains user consent to access that file or folder.

If you acquire access to a file or folder this way, then you should preserve access through the Windows.Storage.AccessCache API for future sessions (for recently used lists and such).

Trying to get to anything else (e.g. absolute file paths) will give an access denied exception. The code you show above will do this--if you use the file picker you'd be using either the StorageFile API or a relative path on a folder that was chosen through the picker.

The static  get[File | Folder]FromPathAsync methods work only for those pathnames to which you have programmatic access, namely appdata and library paths.